# Infinite Call History on Android

Tags: android, logs, phone

Do you know any app that can keep more than 500 calls in my Android Call Log?
I currently use apps that backup my log to csv or xls then load the backup file to my PC when needed. I want something that lets me view the full log from my phone without using my PC or a cloud service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you haven't specified that you want a premium or <s>freeware</s>*(now discontinued)*, I would assume that you are open to both, so you can try [Unlimited Call Log](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softrelay.unlimitedcalllog) By Soft Relay.

**Features**

- Saves and shows all call logs, not just the last 500
- Saves and shows all SMS logs
- Store both Call and Text Message logs on any Android device
- Ultra-fast custom storage, synchronized with Android’s stock call log
- Groups the log entries by contact, date, or type (incoming, outgoing)
- Sortable logs by date, contact, type or duration
- Quick searchable history by contact or phone number
- "Swipe to call" feature makes Unlimited Call Log the best replacement for Android's stock Call Log App
- Two steps deleting ("select one by one" or "select all" plus "delete button") saves time for you
- Statistics based on the entire call log or contact’s call history
- Export call log to CSV/XML file
- Dark/light themes supported

---

Screenshot

[image]
[image]
[image]

<sup>Credits: Google PlayStore (Unlimited Call Log Page)</sup>

Comment: Unfortunately, this app seems no longer be listed on Google Play (I get a 404 following the link). Do you have a secondary source? Maybe it's in some other repository, like F-Droid? Or is [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.softrelay.unlimitedcalllog) its successor?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for pointing it out, seems like they discontinued the freeware, provided a link for premium now

Comment: Thanks for confirming & updating your answer :)

Comment: The app no longer shows up in the Play Store

Answer (score 4):

I have not used it myself (I've not that many calls making it worth looking for such an app), but it looks like **[Spy Call Logs](http://www.appbrain.com/app/spy-call-logs/com.imobappz.spy.calllog)** is exactly what you're looking for. It works locally on the device (so no "backup to PC/cloud"), ans seems to have no limit concerning number of records. From its description:

> It is very useful application when you want to record more than 500 call logs because default Android Call log stores only 500 call logs data.

How does it meet your requirements:

- **keep more than 500 calls in my Android Call Log:** Yes – as described above.
- **instant access to all call log entries on my phone:** Yes. Including sort (incoming/outgoing/missed), call details (date, time and duration of call), possibility to directly call/message from the logs.

---

For an alternative, there's also **[My Call Duration-Unlimited log](http://www.appbrain.com/app/my-call-duration-unlimited-log/com.aaarju.calls)**:

> Un-limited call log access - Once you start using this app, your call logs will be remains available inside application. No 500 call logs limits, now access all logs

This app comes with filtering and stats as well, and additionally can be themed (several themes are included with the app). On the downside, it doesn't seem to support direct call/message from the stored logs.

---

If you've got privacy concerns: Both apps I've mentioned here have access to your call logs *and* to the Internet, so they theoretically could "spy" on you (which gives the first app's name a quite special meaning). In this case, check the [answer of Mr. Alien](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/3269/185) and follow the link in my comment there: [Unlimited Call Log](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.softrelay.unlimitedcalllog) does (currently) not request network access.

<sup>(For other call-log related apps, you can also take a look at [my listings](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=23#group_849))</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I recommend BearContact. It has an unlimited call log:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.skzeng.beardialer&hl=en

It is free and reliable.

Answer (score -1):

[IFTTT](https://ifttt.com) (If This Then That) is a web-application thats links other web-applications but also offers an IOS and Android phone that lets you link events on your phone to those other web-applications. IFTTT can be easily configed to build a call log on a web-based service such as Google Drive or Google Calendar. This log can then be synced based to your device through the offline capabilities of those apps. You could also sync these automatically to your PC

There are examples on IFTTT that can be found [here](https://ifttt.com/recipes?channel=android_phone) and include:

1. Archive your received calls from Android to Google Drive
2. Log phone calls to Google calendar
3. Send an E-mail with the call metadata

Lets look at some of the specific requirements of OP as IFTTT isn't perfect but may be useful for other people with a similar question.

In this case, the OP has stated in comments that they specifically aren't interested in cloud-based backup but it is worth considering given IFTTT offers lots of additional possibilities for what can be done with call metadata.

Whether IFTTT meets the requirement of 'Instant Access' depends on what the OP means. If the OP means 'as quickly as possible' then IFTTT isn't suitable as it requires an internet connection and a coordination between several cloud-based services. If the OP is happy with something that is available after a few minutes then IFTTT is definately worth considering.

Note that internet access is only required for IFTTT to execute and update the call log. Depending on the service used, the data should be available offline.

Anecdotally I did read some reviews that said that the first version of the IFTTT Android app was unreliable but I've seen new versions which mention reliability improvements in the version log since then.

Comment: I've read your answer and I don't understand how it answers the question. The question is asking how to keep more logs on the phone, not how to save logs elsewhere. On a related note, your answer doesn't really contain the information that would be useful — the history of IFTTT isn't relevant, but you should explain how to write an IFTTT rule to accomplish what the question is asking for (or as close as can be done with IFTTT).

Comment: @Gilles, thanks for the comment. There was previously a comment discussion with Izzy regarding how I can improve the quality of this answer. That discussion is no longer here unfortunately. I'll make some more edits.

Comment: I've had a quick look at the meta questions for Software Recs and it feels like I should delete my answer given that it doesn't meet all the user requirements. But then it won't be helpful for people searching for similar solutions.